# Gitlab-Python - Using the API to fork a existing group into a created subgrou

Tags: python, api, gitlab, git-fork

As an automated event, and having had a client artifact subgroup created, using the Gitlab API, I want for fork a existing repo into the newly created subgroup.

Example Repo: Exists (Fork_repo_ID)

Destination: the previously created subgroup

Goal
Through an automation event, and having had a client artifact subgroup created, a repo is forked and the new repo is placed in the proper client subgroup.

I'm going to use the Gitlab-python API to demo this by cmd in python - as far as the  forking goes I'm having trouble finding examples. I have a static project_id to pull the fork from but I'm not sure how to path it to the newest subgroup/at all really. I've found the following for the API

```
   project = gl.projects.get(fork_project_id)
    
    fork = project.forks.create({'namespace': subgroup.path})
```

Does anyone have any reference for this/pathing it the correct way? I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

What you have will work, but using `namespace` is deprecated. Use `namespace_id` or `namespace_path` instead:

```py
project.forks.create({'namespace_id': subgroup.id})
```

Remember, the `python-gitlab` library is just a wrapper around the official GitLab API. You can reference the [projects API fork endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#fork-project) (or API documentation for any other endpoint) for an up-to-date and complete reference.